# Сохранить значение тега в переменную при клике JavaScript

Tags: javascript, события

Есть простой кок на 10 строк, но он не верно работает почему-то
нужно чтобы при клике на кнопку значение сохранялось в переменную и после его можно было вывести

```js
  a = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
  number = '';
  init = function () {
    for (var key in a) {
      num = a[key];
      num.onclick = writeNumber;
    }
  };
  writeNumber = function () {
    number = number + this.value;
    alert(number);
  };
  init();
```

```css
form {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: right;
}
input {
  width: 24.3%;
  margin: 2px 0;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input class="number" type="submit" value="1">
  <input class="number" type="submit" value="2">
  <input class="number" type="submit" value="3">
  <input class="operator" type="submit" value="+">
  <input class="number" type="submit" value="4">
  <input class="number" type="submit" value="5">
  <input class="number" type="submit" value="6">
  <input class="operator" type="submit" value="-">
  <input class="number" type="submit" value="7">
  <input class="number" type="submit" value="8">
  <input class="number" type="submit" value="9">
  <input class="operator" type="submit" value="*">
  <input class="number" type="submit" value="0">
  <input class="operator" type="submit" value="/">
  <input type="submit" name="=">
</form>
```

Comment: так ведь оно сохраняется...

Comment: нет оно перезаписывается каждый раз и выводиться и удаляется я так понимаю. нужно чтобы оно сохранилось и вывелось вот так например document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = number;

Comment: тьфу блин, поудаляйте с кнопок атрибут `type="submit"` т оставте его только на кнопке сабмит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот смотрите, все работает :

```js
a = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
number = '';
init = function() {
  for (var key in a) {
    num = a[key];
    num.onclick = writeNumber;
  }
};
writeNumber = function() {
  number = number + this.value;
  console.log(number);
};
init();
```

```css
form {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: right;
}

input {
  width: 24.3%;
  margin: 2px 0;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input class="number" type="button" value="1">
  <input class="number" type="button" value="2">
  <input class="number" type="button" value="3">
  <input class="operator" type="button" value="+">
  <input class="number" type="button" value="4">
  <input class="number" type="button" value="5">
  <input class="number" type="button" value="6">
  <input class="operator" type="button" value="-">
  <input class="number" type="button" value="7">
  <input class="number" type="button" value="8">
  <input class="number" type="button" value="9">
  <input class="operator" type="button" value="*">
  <input class="number" type="button" value="0">
  <input class="operator" type="button" value="/">
  <input type="button" value="=">
</form>
```

`type="submit"` - значит что ето кнопка отправки формы, определитесь, надо ли она вам или нет, но судя по всему у вас калькулятор и отправлять его никуда не нужно, но даже если нужно `submit` должен быть только один. [Читать про отправку формы и `submit`](https://learn.javascript.ru/forms-submit)

В итоге, я заменил все `type="submit"` на `type="button"` и, судя по всему все работает.

ПС: выводите данные в консоль вместо алерта, очень не удобно каждый раз закрывать ети алерты

Comment: Вот я глупый, конечно вся проблема была в submit. Спасибо, а консоль.лог не работала про этой же причине